# ImportError: No module named 'onnx_backend'?

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, onnx

I have installed ONNx form this URL https://github.com/onnx/onnx , now trying to run some models form here https://github.com/onnx/models#face_detection , the problem is that when importing:

```
import numpy as np
import onnx
```

It works but when I try to import

```
import onnx_backend as backend
```

It gives me below error

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import onnx_backend as backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'onnx_backend'
```

Otherwise I am able to load models without any error; how can I rectify the import error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using -

```
from onnx import backend
```

insteed of

```
import onnx_backend as back
```